# Use Google Sheets vlookup to return the value in an index range

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm working on creating a weekly update sheet of client projects.

The sheet I am pulling from has client names in one of three columns. The client name will only be in one of these three columns.

In essence, I want to consolidate these names into a single column in my weekly update sheet.

My current formula is:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A32,Import!$A$3:$P$1000,{2,3,4},false),))
```

The only problem here is that while it searches across three columns it also requires 3 columns for output.

Is there a way that the formula can be written to consolidate the data into a single column?

Comment: I can't replicate your result. Inputting a row in the `index` argument for `vlookup` only results in Google Sheets looking up the first element in the row and ignoring the rest. Can you share a sample sheet so that people can see and test on?

Comment: Use a text function to aggregate the output, i.e. increase the nesting level. Check out `textjoin`, `join`, and `concat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this formula work as you want:

`=SUBSTITUTE(JOIN("|",ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A32,Import!$A$3:$P$1000,{2,3,4},0),))),"|",)`

It replaces the blank columns with | and then substitutes those for blanks.  This leaves only the value from one of columns B:D on your Import sheet

Comment: You sir, are a god among men.